# Conditionally set method options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to conditionally set options for a method?

Something like...

```
article_url(@article, :host => 'myblog.com' if @user.custom_domain?)
```

So in that case...only setting `host` if the user has a certain option set for their account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
opts = @user.custom_domain? ? {:host => 'myblog.com'} : {}
article_url @article, opts
```

Or a one liner:

```
article_url @article, @user.custom_domain? ? {:host => 'myblog.com'} : {}
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider extracting this into a helper then.