# Is it possible to conditionally pass options to a method in perl?

Tags: perl, methods

Similar to [this question regarding Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948949/conditionally-set-method-options), I'd like to conditionally pass parameters to a method.  Currently, I have it configured as follows:

```
my $recs = $harvester->listAllRecords(
    metadataPrefix => 'marc21',
    metadataHandler => 'MARC::File::SAX',
    set => 'pd',
    from => $from,
    until => $until,
);
```

What I'd like is to be able to conditionally pass the from and/or until parameters, depending on previous code.  This is not syntactically correct, but something like this:

```
from => $from if ($from),
until => $until if ($until),
```

or this:

```
if ($from) {from => $from,}
if ($until) {until => $until,}
```

Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Is this what your are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124138/how-to-pass-optional-parameters-to-a-perl-function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the ternary `?:` operator with list operands:

```
my $recs = $harvester->listAllRecords(
    metadataPrefix => 'marc21',
    metadataHandler => 'MARC::File::SAX',
    set => 'pd',

    $from ? (from => $from) : (),
    $until ? (until => $until) : (),
);
```

It may also be worth knowing about the ["conditional list include" pseudo-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2897939/168657), which in this case would work like

```
...
(from => $from) x !!$from,
(until => $until) x !!defined($until),
...
```

but the ternary operator expression is probably easier to read for most people.

Comment: That did it, thanks! A quick Google and some following reading turned up the "Logical Defined-Or" (`//`), which while only tangentially related to my original question, appears very useful.

Answer (score 6):

The other option is to build a list (or hash) of args and then call the method:

```
my %args = (
    metadataPrefix => 'marc21',
    metadataHandler => 'MARC::File::SAX',
    set => 'pd',
);
$args{from} = $from if $from;
$args{until} = $until if $until;

my $recs = $harvester->listAllRecords(%args);
```